# dendextend: Increase font size of dendogram nodes in groupLabels?

Tags: r

Hi suppose I have the following dendogram label with nodes A, B, C.  Is there a way to change the font size?

```
 library(dendextend) 
data(iris, envir = environment()) 
d_iris <- dist(iris[,-5])
hc_iris <- hclust(d_iris)
dend_iris <- as.dendrogram(hc_iris)
dend_iris=color_branches(dend_iris,k=3, groupLabels= c("A","B","C"))

plot ( dend_iris)
```

plot [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `par()` and this might help:

```
# reduced label size
par(cex=2)
plot(dend_iris, xlab="", ylab="", main="", sub="", axes=FALSE)

#y-axis
par(cex=1)
axis(2)
```